# Asp.net request in queued

Tags: asp.net, performance

I have a problem that is a page load performance. I have analyzed the problem with failed request trace on IIS 7.  The problem is ASP.NET Request Queue Limit and relevant IIS configurations.  You can find an example trace log below.

```
CALL_ISAPI_EXTENSION Dll    Name="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll"     10:59:15.926 
AspNetStart             Data1="GET", Data2="/busqueda.html", Data3="q=ET475MU11"            10:59:15.926 
AspNetReqQueued                                                 10:59:15.926 
AspNetReqDequeued                                               10:59:42.707 
AspNetGetAppDomainEnter                                             10:59:42.707 
AspNetGetAppDomainLeave                                             10:59:42.707 
AspNetAppDomainEnter        Data1="/LM/W3SVC/10/ROOT-1-129434506817181196"                  10:59:42.707
```

My application specifications are;
.NET 4.0 Web form, Classic pipeline application. SQL Server (SQL 2008 R2).  It’s working on Windows server 2008 and IIS 7.5.   Web server is a virtual machine and it has 4 CPU and 10 GB memory.
I have searched this problem on the internet. But I am confused and really don’t understand thread using on IIS, queue limit and relevant configurations.
I need your technical feedback if you have experience this problem and configurations.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the issue with _ASP.NET Request Queue Limit and relevant IIS configurations_

Comment: I will try to following configuration. But if I have understood correctly, “maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU”, “maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU” and “maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU” values can be configured according to web server’ specifications. Also I am not sure it work with Classic/ISAPI mode. <system.web>
        <applicationPool maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU="12" maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU="0" requestQueueLimit="5000"/>
    </system.web>